# What is meant by clock trimming in this MCU register?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I was looking at clock control registers of an MCU from its reference manual [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0365-stm32f302xbcde-and-stm32f302x68-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf). There is a register here called HSITRIM and its default value in binary is 10000 which corresponds 16 in decimal. The default clock frequency is HSI and 8 MHz.

[image]

> **HSITRIM[4:0]:** HSI clock trimming

> These bits provide an additional user-programmable trimming value that is added to the HSICAL[7:0]
> bits.

> It can be programmed to adjust to variations in voltage and
> temperature that influence the frequency of the HSI. The default value
> is 16, which, when added to the HSICAL value, should trim the HSI to 8 MHz ±1%.
> The trimming step (Fhsitrim) is around 40 kHz between two
> consecutive HSICAL steps.

But from the above explanation I don't really understand what is trimming about. The default value of HSITRIM is 16. How is this number related to 40 kHZ or 1% of 8MHz?

If we take the default trimming value of 10000 (decimal 16), and if we increase the value by 1 to 10001 (decimal 17) this doesn't become 1% increase. It is 6% change. (?)

Comment: 8MHz +-1% means `8.01~7.99MHz` in real world; if this tolerance is OK for you, ignore it, if you need higher precision without using a crystal, then calibrate it. 40KHz steps means with trimming, you can get as much as close to 8,000,000 Hz with 40000Hz steps.

Comment: If we take the default trimming value of 10000 (decimal 16), and if we increase the value by 1 to 10001 (decimal 17) this doesn't become 1% increase. It is 6% change. Where does this 40kHz come from? Im struggling with the equation part.

Comment: I came across this now http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-calibrate-the-HSI-clock-signal-STM32F407G-C.php

Answer (score 2):

HSITRIM isn't used by itself. It's added to the value in HSICAL. HSITRIM is only 5 bits, but HSICAL is 8 bits. Presumably the clock is designed so the value in HSICAL will typically be *around* 128 (the middle of an 8-bit range). We then add HSITRIM to that, so a difference of 1 in HSITRIM will change HSITRIM+HSICAL by about one part in 128 (= 0.78%).

The "1%", however, is referring to the default clock trimming. That is, at the factory they test it at 25C, and find a value they can write into HSICAL that gives a clock frequency of 8 MHz +/- 1%. From section 9.2.2 of the document you linked:

> RC oscillator frequencies can vary from one chip to another due to manufacturing process variations, this is why each device is factory calibrated by ST for 1% accuracy at T<sub>A</sub>=25°C.
>
> After reset, the factory calibration value is loaded in the HSICAL[7:0] bits in the Clock control
> register (RCC_CR).

#### Summary

At the factory, they find a value for HSICAL that gives a result within 1% of 8 MHz at 25C. If (for example) you consistently run it hotter or colder than 25C, the HSI clock will probably run a little fast or a little slow at the default trimming. In this case, you can adjust the value in HSITRIM to get it closer to the correct speed again. But keep in mind that it's an RC oscillator, so you shouldn't expect the accuracy or stability you would from (for example) a crystal oscillator (but a crystal oscillator takes longer to stabilize and costs more).

Answer (score 0):

The quoted text says changing the trim value up or down by 2 will adjust the freqency of the 8 MHz oscillator up or down by appoximately 40 kHz.

40 kHz is 0.5% of 8 MHz.

Now the text does not say what happens if changed up or down by 1. The effect may be non-linear.